# Spring - dependency injection - testing with different implementation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

One of the main advantage of using spring dependency injection is for **testing the functionality using same interface with different implementation** without making any changes in the code, that is through injecting these different implementations(dependencies) in configuration file.

Lets take an example where we have developed our application with java configuration/annotation based (**No .xml files at all**).

We have done a code freeze and have deployed the code in server.
Now for a QA team to perform testing they need to inject different implementations for the interface by making changes in configuration file without touching code.

If its a .xml file, devOps team can inject the different implementation by injecting that bean name and can restart the server.
But since we have used the annotations based/java based configuration, How can we achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the main advantage of using spring dependency injection is for
>   testing the functionality using same interface with different
>   implementation

One of main advantages of Spring is indeed the dependency injection facility.
But you will also find very often cases where you have beans with a single implementation :

- beans that rely on an interface but there is only one implementation for it.
- bean that don't rely on any interface but are straight classes that you want to turn into injectable beans.

> We have done a code freeze and have deployed the code in server. Now
>   for a QA team to perform testing they need to inject different
>   implementations for the interface by making changes in configuration
>   file without touching code.

Spring and more generally dependency injection pattern/frameworks are not designed to perform hot swapping or implementation modification of a deployed component without repackaging the component.
At startup, Spring creates its context and loads all required beans for the application in its container.
If you want to change configurations of some beans, the most clean and side effect less way is destroying the spring context/container, repackage the application with the needed changes and restart it.

> If its a .xml file, QA team can inject the different implementation by
>   injecting that bean name and can restart the server.

Ideally, the QA team should test the implementation that you deploy in QA env and that will be used by final users to stay the closest of the real functioning of the application.
Now, if because of some specific constraints, some components to test by the QA should be mocked/stubbed in a some way, just create a different build for that.
Spring Boot Profile and Maven Profile features can help for.